# Apache L and END flag are ignored depending of the environement

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite, cpanel

i'm running a Wordpress on a cpanel and i'd like to user this htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(\/|)\d{4,7} - [L,NC,G]
    RewriteRule ^(\/|)\d{4,7} - [END,NC,G]

    
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301,QSD]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

If i use this htaccess on a cpanel environment, when i access to a url like :
https://www.example.com/12345
i got a 404 instead of a 410

If a i run it on a clean environment using a linux turnkey : it's working properly i got a 410
It seems on a cpanel environment the [L] or [END] flag are ignored

Comment: The only weird things I see about it are the `[NC]` is superfluous and `(\/|)` is usually written as `/?`

Comment: What do you mean that "the [L] or [END] flag are ignored"? If they are ignored then WordPress is presumably being triggered? And you are seeing a WordPress generated response, not Apache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try resetting the 410 error document to default:

```
ErrorDocument 410 default
```

I don't think the problem is related to cPanel as such, but it's possible that the 410 is being converted to a 404 by a server-defined ErrorDocument, which is not uncommon on shared server environments.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(\/|)\d{4,7} - [L,NC,G]
> RewriteRule ^(\/|)\d{4,7} - [END,NC,G]
> ```

But having both these directives doesn't make sense. The second directive is never processed.

Strictly speaking, the `G` flag *implies* `L` anyway. So, the `L` flag is superfluous. (As is the `NC` flag.)

But using `L` or `END` in this context makes no difference.

Comment: Thanks, that did the job !